# Should autocommit of a datasource be set to false?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, transactions, datasource

please see the comments in spring DataSourceTransactionManager.java, function doBegin:

```
// Switch to manual commit if necessary. This is very expensive in some JDBC drivers,
// so we don't want to do it unnecessarily (for example if we've explicitly
// configured the connection pool to set it already).
        if (con.getAutoCommit()) {
            txObject.setMustRestoreAutoCommit(true);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Switching JDBC Connection [" + con + "] to manual commit");
            }
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
```

In the project I'm working on, autocommit is not configured. So it is true by default. We are using Spring to manage transactions, and all SQLs are executed within @Transactional annotated functions. So Transactions are acturally manually committed. Everytime a transaction begin, the db connection is set autocommit to false, and after the transaction exit autocommit is set back to true.  A typical workflow would be (at JDBC level)：

1. conn = dataSource.getConnection();
2. conn.setAutoCommit(false);
3. stmt = conn.createStatement();
4. stmt.executeQuery(...);
5. conn.commit()/ conn.rollback();
6. conn.setAutoCommit(true);

Is setting autocommit back and forth expensive? should we config datasource connection pool autocommit=false for performance reason? to skip the step 2 and step 6.

Answer (score 7):

1) autocommit is totally dependent on the database, what it means is that, each and every statement through the connection will be executed in a separate transaction which is implicitly carried out. Unless and until, you want to use personal coding and avoid those locks being held by multiple statements which could lead to conflicts with other users, there is no need to set the autocommit to false.

2)From performance points of view,

**a) if you have a lot of users and there is some conflict that is occuring because of holding of database locks, 
    then, there may be a need to check into the issues pertaining to it but as a general
    rule,   autocommit was introduced for simplification of stuff for beginners.**

**b) there may be instances where you  need to rollback .**

**c) you want to commit the transaction manually based on a specific condition.**

EDIT: I see you have edited the question, to answer you simply, autocommit=false will force you to write your own commit/rollback/etc, performance is totally dependent on the database, the number of locks held at a moment in real time!!

No. setting autocommit to false and true again will not increase the toll on the system.

NO, do not config datasource connection pool autocommit=false unless you are doing it for some specific reason and are an experienced person. From performance points of view, as i already decalred, it is dependent on the type of database and real time users accessing the database at an instance, for your project, 99.99 percent you wouldn't be needing to set it to false.

setting autocommit to true will just ensure that commit is called after each and every statement.

I also see that you are getting your connection from a datasource, in such cases, it is best to leave the connection with default settings so that the next time that connection is fetched from the pool, there wouldn't be any trouble with the workflow

Hope this helped!!

Comment: i guess these set autocommit commands will need two round trip and cost extra 0.8 milliseconds for each transaction in my test。

Comment: logically, as i see it, the problem will be while setting autocommit to true after a transaction ends that holds various statements, because you are again telling the system to go back to default state and handle everything on its own which is not the case when you set autocommit to false, so there might be 1 roundtrip not two that cost you 0.8milli, well things also depend on what you are doing after that setautocommit to true, if you are just closing the connection, how does it matter ? :D

Answer (score 0):

In bulk operations you can set it off in your session and set again on after bulk operation completion to gain performance.

```
SET autocommit=0;
your code here....
SET autocommit=1;
```

**Update:**

As @codemania explained very well that even there is option to disable autocommit as per your requirement but you should not do this. Even this is basic need of transaction to either successfully commit a set of instructions or rollback, if you do it disable then how you will achieve it.

This will be useful if you are doing some bulky task like data migration etc, for it you can disable autocommit to gain performance but only in that session.

Answer (score -2):

You should set autocommit to true whenever you're issuing database transactions. A database trasaction is a logical unit of work, which usually consists of multiple database operations (usually multiple updates) and you want either all of them to succeed or all of them to fail. With autocommit=false, your changes will not be made persistant until you call commit() on the connection object, so this approach guarantees that all your updates will either succeed or fail (by calling rollback in case of an exception etc).

When autocommit is set to true (the default), you can, for instance, change one table but then on the second update (whether it be an update/insert or delete), an exception may occur and your second table doesn't get updated, thus leaving your database in an inconsistent state.

In conclusion, autocommit=true is OK when just reading data or when the database data model is simple and accessed by few users (so that concurrent access to the same regions of data is very rare and when some database inconsistencies can even be tolerated)